# Split date column into hour segments

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Thank you in advance for taking the time to look at this.

I am looking to take a number of records containing a date field and split them into hour columns with a count in each (sql server).

E.g.

```
SpecialDateColumn  
14/1/15 10:23      
14/1/15 11:34       
14/1/15 12:45       
14/1/15 12:55
```

I'm looking the results in a single row as follows:

```
Date      10  11  12  13 etc
14/1/15   1   1   2   0
```

I've tried to do this using a pivot table, but not had much joy.

Thanks again in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT SpecialDateColumn AS [Date]
    ,DATEPART(HOUR, SpecialDateColumn) [Hour]
FROM < TABLE >
) AL1
PIVOT(COUNT([Hour]) FOR [Hour] IN (
        [0]
        ,[1]
        ,[2]
        ,[3]
        ,[4]
        ,[5]
        ,[6]
        ,[7]
        ,[8]
        ,[9]
        ,[10]
        ,[11]
        ,[12]
        ,[13]
        ,[14]
        ,[15]
        ,[16]
        ,[17]
        ,[18]
        ,[19]
        ,[20]
        ,[21]
        ,[22]
        ,[23]
        )) P;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple enough to write this as conditional aggregation:

```
select cast(SpecialDateColumn as date) as thedate,
       sum(case when datepart(hour, SpecialDateColumn) = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as hour_10,
       sum(case when datepart(hour, SpecialDateColumn) = 11 then 1 else 0 end) as hour_11,
       sum(case when datepart(hour, SpecialDateColumn) = 12 then 1 else 0 end) as hour_12,
       sum(case when datepart(hour, SpecialDateColumn) = 13 then 1 else 0 end) as hour_13
from table t
group by cast(SpecialDateColumn as date)
order by thedate;
```

Answer (score 0):

This way will always get all the hours but is an example with PIVOT. Other than this you can use dynamic SQL to construct the PIVOT either with CASES like Gordon's example or PIVOT

```
select
    *
from (
    select
        CONVERT(DATE,h) D,
        DATEPART(HOUR,h) H
    from (
    select
    '2014-01-01 10:00:01' h
    UNION ALL
    select
    '2014-01-02 11:00:01'
    UNION ALL
    select
    '2014-01-03 10:00:01'
    UNION ALL
    select
    '2014-01-03 14:00:01'
    ) T
) SRC
PIVOT(
    COUNT(H) 
    FOR H IN ([0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23])
) PVT
```

Answer (score 0):

Pivot is the right way imho ... in the snippet below I have an images Table with a field created_date

```
select
    *
from
(
    select
        1 as dummy                       ,
        datepart(hh, created_date)  as h ,
        cast(created_date as date)  as d
    from images
) as t
pivot( count(t.dummy) for t.h in ([9],[10],[11],[12]) ) as pvt
```

and the result from query looks lihe this:

[image]